# Apache camel using HttpEndpoint Options with http4

Tags: java, apache-camel

i am relatively new to camel. I am facing the issue while implementing the following functionality.

Requirement: Call the GET service, if the response is any other status than 200, need to throw a **HttpOperationFailedException** , so that 204 exception i can handle using a onException on my parent route.

I was able to achieve it using the below code:

```
from("direct:parent")
.onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
.onWhen(exchange ->{
    HttpOperationFailedException exe = exchange.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class);
    if(204 == exe.getStatusCode()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})
.setBody(constant(null))
.end()
.to("direct:a");

from("direct:a")
.recipientList("false")
.simple("http4://localhost:8022/test/service?okStatusCodeRange=200-201")
.convertBodyTo(String.class);
```

However the exception is not thrown when using the following code:

```
from("direct:parent")
.onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
.onWhen(exchange ->{
    HttpOperationFailedException exe = exchange.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class);
    if(204 == exe.getStatusCode()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})
.setBody(constant(null))
.end()
.to("direct:a");

from("direct:a")
.to("http4://localhost:8022/test/service?okStatusCodeRange=200-201")
.convertBodyTo(String.class);
```

Would anyone explain what need to be changed to get it working with to instead of a recipientList list ?

Comment: You can try to add the URL as `Exchange.HTTP_URI` header. According to the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) this header will overwrite any directly specified URL. The difference here is, that the URL specified within the header does not support configuration options while the `.to(...)` URI will consider them. If using the HTTP_URI header, you can also use a dummy URL in the `.to(...)` to configure the endpoint with security and related stuff as the actual target to invoke is determined by the HTTP_URI header.

Comment: I tried this, However when i add Uri, getting a message like http4 is not supported when the call is made

Comment: I changed the URI to http call, However still the even even response is 204, the HttpOperationFailedException is not thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you propagate the HTTP URI invocation from `direct:parent` to `direct:a` but maintain a nested exception clause in `direct:parent`, the exception thrown in `direct:a` is **NOT** propagated upwards to the parent route. What you should do, however, is refactor the nested exception clause to a global exception clause.

I've created a simple test case that either mocks the exception thrown on a 204 message or may invoke the real service and fail in case of an 204 response:

```
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithRouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue;

public class Http4ExceptionHandlingTest extends CamelTestSupport {

  @Produce(uri = "direct:parent")
  protected ProducerTemplate template;

  @Override
  public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {

        onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
            .onWhen(exchange -> {
              HttpOperationFailedException
                  exe = exchange.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class);
              return 204 == exe.getStatusCode();
            })
            .log("HTTP exception handled")
            .handled(true)
            //.continued(true)
            .setBody(constant(null));

        from("direct:parent").routeId("parent")
//            .onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
//                .onWhen(exchange -> {
//                  HttpOperationFailedException
//                      exe = exchange.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class);
//                  return 204 == exe.getStatusCode();
//                })
//                .setBody(constant(null))
//            .end()
            .log("Parent start");
            .to("direct:a")
            .log("Parent done");

        from("direct:a").routeId("a")
            .log("a start")
            .to("http4://localhost:8022/test/service?okStatusCodeRange=200-201")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .log("a done");
      }
    };
  }

  @Test
  public void testExceptionHandling() throws Exception {
    // comment the following line out if you want to invoke the real service instead!
    weaveRoute();

    context.start();

    Object response = template.requestBody("foo");

    assertThat(response, is(nullValue()));
  }

  @Test
  public void testSuccessfulResponse() throws Exception {
    // comment the following line out if you want to invoke the real service instead!
    weaveRoute();

    context.start();

    Object response = template.requestBody("bar");

    assertThat(response, is(equalTo("bar")));
  }

  private void weaveRoute() throws Exception {
    context.getRouteDefinition("a").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        this.interceptSendToEndpoint("http4*")
            .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
            .process(exchange -> {
              String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
              if ("foo".equals(body)) {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String location = "";
                HttpOperationFailedException exe =
                    new HttpOperationFailedException("http://bla", 204, "No Content", location,
                                                     headers, "response body");
                throw exe;
              }
            });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I've left the original nested exception clause in the parent route so you can compare the results. The global exception handler got an additional `.handled(true`)` statement which just breaks out of the current route. The documentation therefore states the following:

> If handled is true, then the thrown exception will be handled and Camel will not continue routing in the original route, but break out. However you can configure a route in the onException which will be used instead. You use this route if you need to create some custom response message back to the caller, or do any other processing because that exception was thrown. ([Source](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html))

Not setting the caught exception to `.handled(true)` will actaully result in a presentation of the stacktrace rather then proceed with the execution.

I've added further log statements to visualize the behavior in exception handling. On executing the code presented above you will get an output like:

```
[INFO ] -  - Parent start [            ] [parent] [              ] [main] 
[INFO ] -  - a start [            ] [a] [              ] [main] 
[INFO ] -  - HTTP exception handled [            ] [a] [              ] [main]
```

Instead of `.handled(true)` you may also use `.continued(true)` in order to proceed with the execution as documented:

> If continued is true, then Camel will catch the exception and in fact just ignore it and continue routing in the original route. However if you have a route configured in the onException it will route that route first, before it will continue routing in the original route.

Running the test with an enabled `.continued(true)` and a disabled `.handled(true)` in the global exception clause will produce the following log:

```
[INFO ] -  - Parent start [            ] [parent] [              ] [main] 
[INFO ] -  - a start [            ] [a] [              ] [main] 
[INFO ] -  - HTTP exception handled [            ] [a] [              ] [main] 
[ERROR] -  - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ...). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: null. Handled and continue routing.

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[parent            ] [parent            ] [direct://parent                                                               ] [         8]
[parent            ] [log9              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[parent            ] [to4               ] [direct:a                                                                      ] [         8]
[a                 ] [log7              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[a                 ] [to3               ] [http4://localhost:8022/test/service?okStatusCodeRange=200-201                 ] [         8]
[                  ] [process2          ] [Processor@0x3c7f66c4                                                          ] [         8]
[a                 ] [log6              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[a                 ] [setBody2          ] [setBody[{null}]                                                               ] [         0]

Stacktrace
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [            ] [o.a.c.p.DefaultErrorHandler] [              ] [main] 
org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://bla with statusCode: 204, redirectLocation: 
    at at.erpel.messaginghub.services.unit.routes.rest.Http4ExceptionHandlingTest$2.lambda$configure$1(Http4ExceptionHandlingTest.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    ...
[INFO ] -  - a done [            ] [a] [              ] [main] 
[INFO ] -  - Parent done [            ] [parent] [              ] [main]
```

As can be seen from the simplified log, `.continued(true)` won't break out of the route though will log a message history as well as a stacktrace of the ignored exception.

In case of a nesed exception clause in the parent route while the child route does run into an exception, adding `.handled(true)` or `.continuted(true)` to the nested exception clause has no effect as the actual exception caught in the child route is not propagated to the parent nested exception clause and thus not handled at all.

I've tested the code sample against the mock as well as against a real service which returned a `204` response on receiving a `foo` body and a `200` response on receiving anything else. The `?okStatusCodeRange=200-201` configuration argument therefore works as expected in my case. For completenes: I'm using Camel 2.17.0.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail, I had tried reusing the same in my route. However for me the httpOperationFailureException is not thrown if the service returns a 204, when using .to(). however same works when using .recipentList(). Also able to see that when using the recipentList in the console a message like configuring property: okStatusCodeRange is displayed. However this is not displayed when using .to(). I am using Camel 2.17.2. Will this be causing this issue ?

Comment: The easiest thing to test if Camel 2.17.2 has some issues is to temporarily step back to 2.17.0, as this worked for me like shown in the answer. Have you tried running the test? Does the test work for you? In case the mock version is green, you can comment out `weaveRoute()` within the test and run the test again. This time however, instead of using the mocks the real service should be invoked. If this also works, then the problem may be somewhere else maybe in some other stuff you didn't include in the simplified scenario.

Comment: I tried running the test case by using `weaveRoute()` and after commenting it. The test case works fine. Hence i believe its not a bug in camel 2.17.2. Like you have mentioned, in the actual code i have called the parent route within  `.doTry()` with `.doCatch(exception)` , maybe that's causing the issue . Will try some refactoring. Thanks a lot @Roman Vottner